# Is there an alternative prompt to `input` which allows for better in-line editing?

Tags: python, input, prompt

I'm writing a script which requires user input, and the canonical way in Python is certainly to use `input` or `raw_input`. However, I don't find this particularly forgiving. For example, if I hit <kbd>←</kbd> at the prompt, it inserts the escaped character `^[[D`- hardly useful. Is there a better alternative?

[image: The prompt does not accept left]

Comment: Use the [`readline`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html) module.

Comment: BTW, `raw_input()` no longer exists. In Python 3, `input()` does what `raw_input()` did in Python 2.

Comment: Just to make sure you don't skip by @Barmar's correct answer, just installing `readline` automatically gives you command-line editing abilities in all of your Python shells and the `input` function.  It is magic worth its weight in gold.

Comment: @Barmar: `readline` is not available on all platforms.

Comment: @martineau Why doesn't the documentation page mention that? What platforms isn't it available on?

Comment: @Barmar: I've wondered that myself for many years, but can attest that it's not available on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use navigation inside with input you can try:

```
import readline
```

Just add it in the beginning, this will give you all the features you are looking for.